Ho to fix "Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate"
@Composable fun MyComposeUI() {
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0.5f) }
}

the error is on the line:
var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0.5f) }

should ?I choose the suggested fix: import operator 'State.getValue' ?
this is a screenshot showing the error:


The message is very clear in your IDE :( just import them

@Al-Taie No there is a bug(2024.1.2 Patch 1) although all the imports are correct, it still gives the error, since i have question ban(idk why), i'm unable to ask

Place the text cursor over the error message and press Alt+Enter to automatically create the missing import statement:
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue

Since this is a var you need to repeat the above to also add this:
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue


You can even enable the "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" option for Kotlin in the Android Studio settings under Editor > General > Auto Import so the imports are added automatically when you tpye, you do not even need to press the above shortcut anymore.
